# Where does my app save files in external storage?

Tags: android, storage, external, android-sdcard

I am using this code to save some text in the external storage.

```
                String fileName = "zadTest";
            String text = "Hello World!";
            if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())){
                File textFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),fileName);
                FileOutputStream fos = null;
                try {
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(textFile);
                    fos.write(text.getBytes());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally {
                    if (fos != null) {
                        try {
                            fos.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

But I don't know where to look for it exactly so I can't check if I am doing this correctly and I don't know if I really put some data into external storage. I checked my SD card but couldn't find it I also tried to run this app on emulator but also cant find the file.

I have put these in the manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Additional question: Should I bother with "finally" in try/catch blocks or should I just put all the code in "try" and skip "finally"?

Comment: print `file.getPath();` in Log.v() to findout the actual path of File

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` return the Internal Storage path(Path where DCIM folder, Download folder etc. are present

Comment: Regarding the additional question: if you're OK with targeting API level 15 and higher (Android 4.0.3 and later), and remember saying so in your manifest, you should use the sanity-preserving try-with-resources statement. See e.g. https://www.journaldev.com/592/java-try-with-resources

Comment: On which OS you are trying to execute your code? If its >= Android M then ensure that permission has been granted to app.

Comment: according to me, it saves the file into the internal storage, so check once into internal storage if you didn't find the file then your Android OS version higher so you need to put run-time permission for that.

Comment: @Sagar I am using Android 6.0. How can I do that? I only know about putting those <uses-premission/> I already have inside manifest

Comment: @hdw3 
please check the code which attaches below.

Comment: Manual way is to go to the Settings -> App -> Your Application -> Permission -> enable all of them and try again. 
If it works implement permission model

Comment: @Sagar that's the temporary solution if anyone clear data of the application then permission removed and again we need to follow steps given by you. so run-time permission is a better option for developers.

Comment: @MaheshKeshvala As I said in my comments "If it works **implement permission model**" which means implement run-time permissions as recommended by Google

Answer (score 0):

Here I placed code with run-time permission put this and check again
Put this permission in on create and call request permission in that.

```
   private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 101;

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermission(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CODE);
        } else {

            String fileName = "zadTest";
            String text = "Hello World!";
            if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
                File textFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), fileName);
                FileOutputStream fos = null;
                try {
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(textFile);
                    fos.write(text.getBytes());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (fos != null) {
                        try {
                            fos.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

After permission code, call this method

```
protected void requestPermission(String[] permissionType, int
        requestCode) {

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            permissionType, requestCode
    );
}
```

Comment: After adding your code app asked for a SD card permission but after that It crashed is it because i have changed requestPermission()?   ?                   ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

                        }, REQUEST_CODE)

Comment: Your code is working, thanks for update. It asked me for a permission but then crashed and no files in SD so I guess that my saving function is to blame?

Comment: unfortunately not, something is still wrong, I have created a new answer to avoid the mess in comments.